# Adjust placeholder size in html5 masterpage code

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, html5, responsive

I'm designing a SharePoint site for a work project that will have a responsive HTML5 front-end rather than the standard bland SharePoint interface.  Rather than building from scratch, I've opted to take the free masterpage code from http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/v5-responsive-html5-master-page/ and modify it.  Here's my question for the SharePoint Designer and HMTL5 experts:

I'm trying to get rid of the left sidebar content and make the main page content placeholder the entire width of the formatted white part of the page (not the beige background).  I've moved all of the left placeholders out of the way, but I can't seem to figure out what is constraining the size of `PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea` and `PlaceHolderMain` (shown in screenshot of visual/code view).  Even though there is space to the left of them, I cannot get those two placeholders to become wider.  Where is that specific size being defined in the code?  I've attached a PDF of the masterpage code since I can't upload word documents.

Thank you!

[image: screenshot of code/visual design view]

Answer (score 0):

Im not going to paste a straight answer, but I believe that if you use a simple web inspection tool such as IE developer toolbar or firebug for firefox, you will likely find a margin-left for the main place holder, or some other css tweak, provided that you already removed the necessary markup on the left side.